# Get Javascript interface keys as string (like an Enum)

Tags: javascript, typescript

My request is actually really simple but I have found almost nothing of the sort online. Picture this, you have an interface like so:

```
interface MyInterface: {
  propertyA: number;
  propertyB: string;
  propertyC: boolean;
}
```

Now you want to use the name of a field to access its value dynamically so you do something like `object['propertyA']`, where `object` is of type `MyInterface`.

However, passing `'propertyA'` as a raw string is impractical and dangerous because if you rename it or change the interface the code won't work. (And it doesn't get picked up by typescript but I'm not sure this is possible anyway).

**Ideally, I would like to do something like this** `MyInterface.propertyA`, I was saddened that this doesn't seem to exist, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't.

And now before you say that's what `object.propertyA` is for, I have simplified the concept to make it easy to understand but the use case is not exactly this. I might pass fields of an interface as strings from react components within the JSX to make use of a reusable method or I could be checking whether a string matches a subset of keys in an interface to display errors accordingly.

Autogenerating an enum from the interface/class is not a bad solution although not ideal as it still incurs an overhead but as long as it doesn't need to be updated each time the interface changes and it doesn't depend on the type of the interface's properties then that's not bad.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the question what you're looking for here, unless it's `keyof MyInterface` (which is a union of string literal types for the keys of the interface, so not just any string): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#handbook-content If that's not what you're looking for, please add a concrete example to the question and point to the bit that doesn't work as you'd like it to, so we can help you with it.

Comment: I'm not looking to generate a type (as keyof would) I'm looking to get a string for a particular key of an interface. In the example above I am looking for a way to get the string "propertyA" from the interface by doing something like MyInterface.propertyA.
This makes sense in the context of today's IDEs that will easily pick up references to the same variable but can be more unpredictable when you pass a string in quotation marks.
Let me know if you need more clarification and thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces don't exist at runtime, so there's no way to get the property names of an interface as runtime values. What you *can* do, though, is go the other way: Have a "model" object:

```js
const myInterfaceModel = {
    propertyA: 42,
    propertyB: "x",
    propertyC: true,
};
```

Then define the interface using that object:

```js
type MyInterface = typeof myInterfaceModel;
```

That defines `MyInterface` just as it is in your question.

Then you can create an object that has the property names as strings, like this:

```js
const myInterfaceKeys = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(myInterfaceModel).map((key) => [key, key])
);
```

Now, if we just did that, `myInterfaceKeys` would be (effectively) `Record<string, string>`, which isn't useful for devex. But we can do better by using a mapped type on it:

```js
type KeyNames<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: Key;
};
// ...
const myInterfaceKeys = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(myInterfaceModel).map((key) => [key, key])
) as KeyNames<MyInterface>;
```

**Now**, its type matches its runtime value, and we get useful autocompletion:

[image: IDE showing the code myInterfaceKeys. with a list of possible properties containing all the properties from MyInterface]

Example usage (just a basic function, but could as easily be a React component):

```js
function example(obj: MyInterface, key: keyof MyInterface) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}

declare let exampleObject: MyInterface;

example(exampleObject, myInterfaceKeys.propertyA);
```

Here's that all together ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDkCGBbCBnAPAFQHxQF4oBvAKCgqgG04QoBLAOygGt4B7AMymwF0AuWPADcpAL6jSAY3aN0wKChABJRsAgAnTkikQAsuwAmEADaES5SmA3tIG0AEFBAFgBMAGksVrtzaABCggBEAB5BnpRQPnagAMKCwBoArhCeEqSgkFB6Kmqa2rrmmRBcirnqWjr6RqaiAPR1lAB6APyk0rLyZaoVBRC06OYA8gBGAFYQUsAAdJw2KACiahr0GAAUXlCjE1PTbCDoa0o9+VUGxiYAlNMoSGBra-uXhPhU++6s8LyXpM9Ig7RkGgsDkTpVdLhJMc8uD+vB0KQGpFkZEmoAkIgxaJ44GgSCimnoRigSE4FSgwAAFvRBsB2FB0BBoJTcUlaTIUGATBBgITGO0kQsQqhOdAkugkABzaBrMZihR4kb-ehSKCcJKMKa8j4jVlQGRJEyGYmDCBKkx0Ea4qAAJVNUz17A5sggaku-Haao1PNkUAgQo5XLW7HGglBML6H32gn2pTDvSqzzIkRkcnYXOmJnYEqD4zeX0uojE7WMUhMSA00C5Cj9wq520mwFD5VOukkNYDEDW7ZF9amH2h8d0A2m0T8IAcBaAA)):

```js
type KeyNames<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: Key;
};

const myInterfaceModel = {
    propertyA: 42,
    propertyB: "x",
    propertyC: true,
};
type MyInterface = typeof myInterfaceModel;
//   ^? type MyInterface = { propertyA: number, propertyB: string; propertyC : boolean }

const myInterfaceKeys = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(myInterfaceModel).map((key) => [key, key])
) as KeyNames<MyInterface>;

myInterfaceKeys
//             ^−−−− Type a period after this to see the autocompletion
```

Usually I'd just use string literals (`example(exampleObject, "propertyA")`) since the IDE will offer the appropriate choices, and since `keyof MyInterface` is restrictive, if you remove a property, any code that referenced it with a string literal would stop compiling. But if you want that object with the keys on it, you can do the above to achieve that. (Also, I just tried, and if you use your object of keys, renaming a property works throughout, whereas the string literals didn't.)

Comment: This is really cool but you're right that it isn't really worth it, thank you so much for the effort though I learnt a lot! Would it be any simpler if it were a class instead of an interface?

Comment: @LiamClarkGutiérrez - My pleasure. :-) It wouldn't matter from a type perspective whether it was a `class` or an `interface`, because *instance properties* aren't discoverable (without creating an instance) unless they're all accessors, and you probably don't want that. :-) Re being worth it: The renaming a property thing I mentioned surprised me, I would have expected the rename to fix the string literals too, so that was one advantage of doing your keys object. Aside from that, I find I do something along these lines (though not quite this) when ...

Comment: ... I have a type I'm going to need to write a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for, since that's a runtime structure that needs to know the property names.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
enum Direction {
  Up = "u",
  Down = "d",
  Left = "l",
  Right = "r",
}

interface MyDirection  {
    [Direction.Up]:string;
    [Direction.Down]:number;
}

const obj:MyDirection = {
    [Direction.Up]: 'up',
    [Direction.Down]:12,

}


console.log(obj[Direction.Down], Direction.Down)
```

Comment: The objective is exactly that but the implementation doesn't work because it requires you to have an unknown type. I would also rather it built the enum from the interface or class rather than the other way around because I often use class-validator so I need to define properties for each field. Thanks for the reply though, much appreciated.